# Spring Boot Using No Longer Supported Version Of BouncyCastle (through CrashHub)

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Spring boot is using an older version of CrashHub (crashub.version in POM) that uses an old version of bouncycastle that using the class PemReader.  This conflicts with the latest version of bouncycastle I am using in my application.  Can you update Spring Boot or is there a work around I can do.  Right now I get the exception below when I try to ssh into my application:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/openssl/PEMReader
    at org.crsh.ssh.term.URLKeyPairProvider.loadKeys(URLKeyPairProvider.java:54)
    at org.apache.sshd.common.keyprovider.AbstractKeyPairProvider.getKeyTypes(AbstractKeyPairProvider.java:53)
    at org.apache.sshd.server.session.ServerSession.sendKexInit(ServerSession.java:127)
    at org.apache.sshd.server.session.ServerSession.<init>(ServerSession.java:60)
    at org.apache.sshd.server.session.SessionFactory.doCreateSession(SessionFactory.java:43)
    at org.apache.sshd.common.session.AbstractSessionFactory.createSession(AbstractSessionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.sshd.common.AbstractSessionIoHandler.sessionCreated(AbstractSessionIoHandler.java:36)
    at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Acceptor$AcceptCompletionHandler.completed(Nio2Acceptor.java:128)
    at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Acceptor$AcceptCompletionHandler.completed(Nio2Acceptor.java:109)
    at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:126)
    at sun.nio.ch.Invoker$2.run(Invoker.java:218)
    at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMReader
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.doLoadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:170)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:136)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 15 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1):

1.3.0 is the latest version of Crashub and that's the version that Spring Boot supports so there's nothing that can be done on the Spring Boot side of things. Assuming that you don't want to downgrade your Bouncycastle dependency, your only easy choice is to stop using Crashub.

A more involved alternative would be to fork Crashub and make the changes necessary for it to work with your desired version of Bouncycastle.

Comment: CRaSH uses bouncycastle `1.49` that was released in June 2013. We can try to bounce that to `1.50` or even `1.5.1` but other use cases would probably break I assume. This sounds more related to how Bouncycastle manage the backward compatibility of their API.